# Sqlite database unable to open after win apps c# deployment on other pc

Tags: c#, sqlite, deployment, connection-string

I have created an windows application with sqlite database. My sqlite db file is stored in the debug folder of the project.I have used Data Set on several forms to display the data.  The setup works fine on my machine but as i install it on other pc's it gives the exception unable to open database as shown in the img.([image: Exception after deployment]

My app.config code is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="RConnString" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Pathology lab\Pathology lab\bin\Debug\Pathology.sqlite"
            providerName="System.Data.Sqlite" />

        <add name="Pathology_lab.Properties.Settings.PathologyConnectionString"
            connectionString="data source=&quot;C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Pathology lab\Pathology lab\bin\Debug\Pathology.db;"
            providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="screen_shot.Properties.Settings.PathorecordConnectionString1"
      connectionString="Data Source=&quot;Pathorecord.db&quot;;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
    </connectionStrings>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I am not able to get exact mistake but I think there is a problem with the connection string. Plz help as i am new to this stuff.

Comment: Does this issue resolved, I'm facing same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

If you install your app to another pc, I´m quit sure there is NOT the same directory structure as on your development pc. If you 'install' your app with an installer your binaries will possibly be located somewhere in 'Program Files', not in YOUR Visual Studio Projects Directory.

And further, don´t try to locate your db in the directory where your bin´s are.

Comment: yes the app is been located at default company name folder / appname in program files.
So wht should i do nw any suggetions??

Comment: You tell your customer where to store the database. If your app is a single user db, you can use the Special Folder "ProgramData" for it.

Comment: I have tried doing it on other pc , & also changed the connection string path as per the location but it didn't work

Comment: please specify exact what "it did not work". The screen shoot you provided doesn´t show everything. and try Google for: 'SQLite connection strings' (without the qoutes)

Comment: Paste the complete text of the error message and provide it here

Comment: this is the only excpetion i m getting after installation, if i click continue it opens the form but does not show any data on the bounded controls

Comment: The data is not fetched on the bounded controls and , all the forms on which i have used data set on certain controls to fetch the data shows this unable to open database exception but the forms which does not contain any Data Set are working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71323/discussion-between-thomas-krojer-and-ameya-bedarkar).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  To solve it I change the connection string datasource to the c: folder. So I had to put my database on the target computer.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score -1):

Alter it because you used absolute dir path. Make it  '. ' static.
'


'